# How to undefine an environment variable in ant

Tags: ant, environment-variables

I am running Ant to exec another process. This other process has problems with some environment variables that are present. I want these environment variables to be undefined when I exec the other process.

Of course I can undefine the environment variable prior to running Ant. However I am interested in undefining the variable within Ant prior to execing the other process.

So I have at the time of calling Ant an environment with:

```
SOME_VAR=a-value
```

And I have in my build.xml:

```
..<exec exacutable="program.exe>...
```

And my program.exe chokes on the fact that `SOME_VAR` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec task has a `newenvironment` attribute which when set to `true` clears the current environment. Use together with nested `env` elements.